# rewrite php code to avoid failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Tags: php

I have been searching for the correct answers on how to to fix this common error on php code: `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!` I really think that the solution lies in rewriting the code to bypass the the `User-Agent` http header in the code. The file I need to access is on the same server as this code. I need help on how I can rewrite the function part of this script:

```
function runapp($dir,$latdeg,$latmin,$latsec,$longdeg,$longmin,$longsec)
{
    global $_english;

    $query= ($_english ? 'http://esnig.org/cgi-bin/ntv2_geo2_e.cgi' : 'http://esnig.org/cgi-bin/ntv2_geo2_f.cgi').
        '?' . PAR_DIR     .'=' . $dir .
        '&' . PAR_LATDEG  .'=' . $latdeg .
        '&' . PAR_LATMIN  .'=' . $latmin .
        '&' . PAR_LATSEC  .'=' . $latsec .
        '&' . PAR_LONGDEG .'=' . $longdeg .
        '&' . PAR_LONGMIN .'=' . $longmin .
        '&' . PAR_LONGSEC .'=' . $longsec;


    $response=file($query); 

    foreach ($response as $value)
    {
        echo $value;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

from file_get_content manual page:

> Note: If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces,
>   you need to encode the URI with urlencode().

So try to urlencode your query parameters before.
Moreover I suggest to use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to get documents from internet url

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, when I do a request to those URLs, I get a 403 Forbidden response. Could that be it?

If not, it seems you don't test the runapp() function params for having a non-empty value. They could be empty strings. What happens if you do a request with some values empty? You would get malformed query parameters.

In short: you should check your params for length or !empty or some such and only append them to the query string if they are set.